Gitlab Pipeline failes without and modifications
When I try to deploy my magento 1.9, the phpcs pipeline fails, although nothing was changed in the piplines.
I got following in the logs screen:
$ chown -R 0:0 ~/.ssh
$ composer config --global --auth gitlab-token.gitlab.com $GITLABACCESSTOKEN
$ composer config --global --auth github-oauth.github.com $GITHUB_TOKEN
$ composer require --dev micheh/phpcs-gitlab --no-scripts --ignore-platform-req=composer-plugin-api
In CurlDownloader.php line 623:
                                                                               
  The "https://packages.firegento.com/include/all%241796ea8f9d50925f8785013cd  
  98eec07e9470304.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )             
                                                                               
require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: phpcs-quality-report.json: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory 
ERROR: No files to upload

I tried to install the packages locally, it worked!
